# Whats the usage of logic buffer( NC7SP126) in this design, how to troubleshooting it?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, buffer

I am troubleshooting my devices which are subjected to battery drain issue. I  have never worked with this buffer chip before. Can Anyone can tell me what is the purpose of adding this chip to the Microprocessor? Will malfunction of this buffer chip affect battery life of the design?

The design used 3.6V lithium battery. MCU is MSP430F155, operate under 2.8V.

Any input will be appreciated, Thanks!

[image]

Comment: which program does the image come from? ...i really like how the MCU symbol is presented

Comment: @jsotola - it looks like OrCAD.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this buffer is to isolate the battery from the A/D converter on P6.3. You have to set P1.4 to high to measure the battery voltage, to low to cut the connection and save battery charge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Janka, can i understand that this buffer is used to control the on/off of the ADC section in MCU? I am still a little confused here.

Comment: No. This buffer is connecting the battery to the ADC input. Or not, which is controlled by the MCU. That's done because the 2x100kΩ resistor network needed because of the lower µC voltage would otherwise drain the battery.

Comment: Janke, so in short, this buffer is used for providing battery power to MCU ADC input to read by connecting them together?